# How to declare Filter attribute globally in Global.asax.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute

I have implemented one action filter in my MVC project. Now I want to add it globally so that I do not need to write filter attribute just above the action methods. I am using BundleMinifyInlineJsCss nuget package.

I have tried with following code in Global.asax.cs file:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ReplaceTagsAttribute());
```

Here is my filter code:

```
 public class ReplaceTagsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter = new BundleAndMinifyResponseFilter(filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter);                         
    }
 }
```

I am getting an error: Filtering is not allowed. How can I declare it Globally?

Thanks.

Comment: You apply this attribute for a Controller or Action method?

Comment: For Action method. I can successfully add it if I manually write attribute to Action method. But I want to add this to all action methods.

Comment: try `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(..)`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: In Global.asax.cs file. Right?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: It gives me an error: Nop.Web.Customization.ActionFilter.ReplaceTagsAttribute' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: apparantly the error message indicates you're using a `Type` like a `Variable`.

Comment: Can you show your full error message,especial trace information?

Comment: @Ankita - are you trying to add global filters in NopCommerce or simple mvc project ?

Comment: @AjinderSingh: NopCommerce project

Comment: @SirwanAfifi: I have tried your solution but  It still gives me the same error.

Comment: @Ankita -  try the posted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think adding a null check will work for you.

```
    public class ReplaceTagsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
 if (response.Filter == null) return; // <-----
response.Filter = new BundleAndMinifyResponseFilter(response.Filter);

    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, now it works. Why we need to do this? Can you please explain?

Comment: It seems Filtering not allowed at that moment So applied a check to make sure Filtering is Allowed.

Comment: And at which moment Filtering is not allowed?

Comment: I can't say actually . May be try to debug from the start and check whenever your filter get called.